# Error while attempting to program page creation on google sites

Tags: java

I'm trying to programmatic-ally add pages to my Google Site using Java. 
This is the code:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;

import com.google.gdata.client.sites.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.PlainTextConstruct;
import com.google.gdata.data.XhtmlTextConstruct;
import com.google.gdata.data.sites.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;
import com.google.gdata.util.XmlBlob;


public class PageCreate {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    WebPageEntry createdEntry = createWebPage("New Webpage Title", "<b>HTML content</b>");
    System.out.println("Created! View at " + createdEntry.getHtmlLink().getHref());
}
private static void setContentBlob(BaseContentEntry<?> entry, String pageContent) {
      XmlBlob xml = new XmlBlob();
      xml.setBlob(pageContent);
      entry.setContent(new XhtmlTextConstruct());
    }

    public static WebPageEntry createWebPage(String title, String content)
        throws ServiceException, IOException, MalformedURLException {
      SitesService client = new SitesService("*****-pagecreate-v1");
      client.setUserCredentials("***********", "*********");

      client.site = "intratrial2"; -> ***SYNTAX ERROR REPORTED***

      //ContentFeed contentFeed = client.getFeed(new URL(buildContentFeedUrl()), ContentFeed.class);
      WebPageEntry entry = new WebPageEntry();
      entry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct(title));

      setContentBlob(entry, content); // Entry's HTML content

      return client.insert(new URL(buildContentFeedUrl()), entry);
    }


      public static String buildContentFeedUrl() {
          String domain = "*****";  // OR if the Site is hosted on Google Apps, your domain (e.g. example.com)
          String siteName = "intratrial2";
          return "https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/" + domain + "/" + siteName + "/";
        }
}
```

If i comment out the line with syntax error i get the following error report on running:
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException: Internal Server Error
Internal Error

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here and I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: Interestingly, the public GData api does not mention a SiteService.client field. Can you add a link to the javadoc for that class?

Comment: That's kinda the problem. The documentation specifically directs me to declare "client.site=SiteName" { [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_java) under the heading "Creating Content"}. But like you said the GData api does not mention the field. So I'm not sure what they want me to do.

Comment: Hmm... that looks like it's left over from a different version of Javascript; have you tried looking at a network trace of the XML requests that your program sends and comparing them with the example XML requests shown at the docs?